# How to confirm what service is running on a port identified by nmap?

Tags: nmap, ports, network-scanners

Probing with nmap returns BlackICE on a couple of ports however it seems to be a really old tool [according to these manuals](https://manualzz.com/doc/23825809/blackice-user-s-guide).

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-10-16 20:27 EDT
Nmap scan report for _gateway (192.168.0.1)
Host is up (0.059s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE         VERSION
80/tcp   open     http            lighttpd
443/tcp  open     ssl/https?
5000/tcp open     upnp            MiniUPnP 1.5 (Linux 2.6.18_pro500; UPnP 1.0)
8081/tcp filtered blackice-icecap
8082/tcp filtered blackice-alerts
Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6.18
```

Is it really blackice or is the nmap database stale?

Anyone know how to get more info about the service running on these ports?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it really blackice or is the nmap db stale?

It is probably not blackice. This is just an educated guess what might be running on port 8081 based on the [nmap-services](https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/nmap-services) database. The port is not [officially assigned to a specific service](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) but was in the past used for blackice. It could be anything - or even nothing (see below).

> Anyone know how to get more info about the service running on these ports?

Since the port is shown as filtered, no connection can be established to it. This means one cannot interact with the service to find more information about it. In fact, there might not even be a service running at all. To cite from [nmap basics](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html) on  what *filtered* means:

> Nmap **cannot determine whether the port is open** because packet filtering prevents its probes from reaching the port. The filtering could be from a dedicated firewall device, router rules, or host-based firewall software.